# Change rectangle color in Rave runtime Delphi

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

We print database records in rave using rvproject1 and rvdatasetconnection1 and that works.
How to acomplish this in rave:
If Adotabel1.fieldbyname('something').asstring = 'something' then
 Rectangle1 on a data band.color=black
else
Rectangle1 on a data band.color=green

Comment: I dont have Rave but I think Onnext event of rvdatasetconnection can be used to check the condition and access the Rectangle BKcolor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rawn,

I believe you must download the Visual Designer Guide.pdf located here 
 
http://www.nevrona.com/Rave/downloadbe.html. What you want to accomplish can be done in several ways(with editor events, from Delphi code, etc). In the manual you will find exactly how to code the band or datatext onbeforeprint event(Rave Report 'language' is very similar to Delphi). At this moment I don't have the time for making you an example.

best regards,
Radu